# Is it Possible to Convert a JavaScript/jQuery Image Gallery In To .Swf Format? Or Into Some Other "non-browser" Medium?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flash

Is it Possible to **Convert** a Image gallery, Photo slider, Image plugin **consist with** (HTML, CSS, Javascript/ jQuery) **In To .Swf Format? Or In To Some Other "non-browser" Medium?**

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it would be easy to convert it to Flash – even though ActionScript (Flash) is really just a dialect of ECMAScript (JavaScript) – but depending on what you mean by "non-browser medium" maybe converting it to a standalone native application would be what you need. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176450/building-a-windows-app-w-embedded-browser-javascript-hooks/5176624#5176624) that I posted few hours ago about Appcelerator Titanium, which allows you to convert your JavaScript web apps to native apps on Windows, Mac, Linux, iPhone, Android.

Comment: Thanks Rsp and you got right.  
Further, do you know that, in Which "Windows Program", the stand alone "Image Gallery App" Will Open?, after Conversion into a "Windows App".

Comment: Sorry but I have no experience with that, this is something that I found quite recently. You may take a look at this [lecture by Jeff Haynie](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RplTiVaxx7s) to learn more about Appcelerator.

Comment: Thanks Rsp. Also, some information regarding my query exist Here [link](http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/desktop/get_started). Please read it.